# Control Video Speed on VLC conveniently

Tags: macos, video, vlc

I prefer changing the video speed on VLC on my MacOS but pressing them once increases/decreases the speed by **0.5x**  which is quite troublesome. Also, I know the keyboard shortcuts to increase/decrease the speed and I **don't** want to change it using the mouse under the `Playback -> Playback Speed`.

I wanted the **Change-Speed** to be around **0.1x** so that a single click increases or decreases the speed by **0.1x**, similar to the [Video Speed Controller Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/videospeed/) for Chrome/Firefox Browsers.

Changing the value at `Preferences -> Input/Codecs -> Playback speed` changes the default speed of the video.

Can anyone help me change that by **0.1x**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Faster` and `Slower` option in the Hotkeys Section changes the speed by **0.5x**.

Instead, you've to use the `Faster(fine)` and `Slower(fine)` option to increase and decrease the speed by **0.1x**.

Preferences > Hotkeys > Set values for Faster(fine), Slower(fine)